# How to remove repeated pixels from different images?

Tags: image-editing, pictures, watermark

Say I have multiple pictures, all with the same object at the same position, e.g. a water mark. Is there any way I could edit these images so that the object in all pictures are removed, and are replaced with white pixels?

Comment: Yes, you can. But what will you replace that object with? White pixels?

Comment: If you do have a moving image it might be possible to restore but it's unlikely and would require special software/a lot of work. Oh and you might be violating the license terms depending on the your agreement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume all files are of the same size, format and watermark is located in the same section of the image....

Then you can use any program that allows to record macros and batch process images. Think of it as applying a watermark on top of watermark for multiple files.

Photoshop would do the job for you. Example is below.

You can record an action (macro) in which you apply a small patch of white pixels on top watermark area of one of the images:

```
 Actions > Create new action
```

Give a name to the action and hit <kbd>Ok</kbd>

Now you are recording. Do whatever manipulations you wish to do to the file. As far as I understood from your question that would be applying the patch of white pixels over the watermark area. Then save and close the file.

Hit <kbd>Stop</kbd> to finish recording.

Now you can use:

```
 File > Automate > Batch
```

... and apply your newly created action to the entire folder full of images.

*Note: Please be aware of potential copyright infringements. This is entirely your responsibility to comply with the copyright laws of the region where you are located*